# What is the current usage of "aller + infinitive" vs. conjugated future forms?

Tags: usage, temps-grammatical, auxiliaires, futur

I saw [this comment](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/29946/why-is-the-romanian-tense-system-so-simple-compared-to-other-romance-language?noredirect=1#comment63904_29946) on another question of mine somewhere else. It claims that "*aller* + infinitive" is used more than conjugated future forms. For example, *je vais avoir* vs. *j'aurai* (*I am going to have* vs *I will have*).

What is the current usage of these two forms? Does it vary by geological positions or cultural areas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is so much akin to conjugation that the French grammatical establishment nowadays calls that construction a tense, the [futur proche](https://conjugaison.lemonde.fr/conjugaison/search?verb=planter).

There is no problem in using it : it's standard French and it dates of old; the current usage, the same as it ever was, corresponds to that of the English verbal form in the progressive "to be going to" followed by an infinive.

**Example**

> Ils vont faire les choses comme il faut dorénavant.
>   From now on they are going to do things right.

the French hadn't so far realised they really had to contend with a new tense ; it's most probably their recent studies of English grammar that woke them up to this new way of thinking!

It must be said, however, that not everyone is agreed upon considering this form as [constituting a real tense](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/frfuturproche.php).

Comment: Or maybe, [there is no *real future tense* in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_tense). Thus this french *construction tense* would be the equivalent of the English form.